# Spring Boot UnsatisfiedDependencyException on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I create an MVC API in spring with `CrudRepository` implementation and receive `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`.

The first time I tried with `@Autowired` annotation, but not work

Controller code:

```
    package marcel.pirlog.licenta.userManagement.controllers;

    import marcel.pirlog.licenta.userManagement.services.IAccountService;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController("/account")
    public class LoginController {

        IAccountService accountService;

        public LoginController(IAccountService accountService) {
            this.accountService = accountService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(name = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<String> getAll(){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(accountService.findAll().toString());
        }

    }
```

Service code:

```
    package marcel.pirlog.licenta.userManagement.services;

    import marcel.pirlog.licenta.userManagement.entities.AccountEntity;
    import marcel.pirlog.licenta.userManagement.repositorys.IAccountRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class AccountService implements IAccountService {

        private final IAccountRepository accountRepository;

        public AccountService(IAccountRepository accountRepository) {
            this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        }

        @Override
        public List<AccountEntity> findAll() {
            List<AccountEntity> result = (List<AccountEntity>)accountRepository.findAll();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Repository code:

```
    @Repository
    public interface IAccountRepository extends CrudRepository<AccountEntity, Long> {
    }
```

UnsatisfiedDependencyException received:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name '/account' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\parlo\Documents\GitHub\licenta\ProiectLicenta\Server\user-management\target\classes\marcel\pirlog\licenta\userManagement\controllers\LoginController.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'accountService' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\parlo\Documents\GitHub\licenta\ProiectLicenta\Server\user-management\target\classes\marcel\pirlog\licenta\userManagement\services\AccountService.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'IAccountRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class
>   marcel.pirlog.licenta.userManagement.entities.AccountEntity ...

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? Before 4.3 (I think) you still need to add @ Autowire on the constructor in you @ Service as well.

Comment: I put @Autowired on the service contructor, but not work. I receive same exception

Comment: @MarcelPirlog could you please clean and install the project?

Comment: Ah - add @Entity on your AccountEntity.

Comment: It seems your there's a problem with your source folder. Have a look here. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning Hope this helps

Comment: medTech, I try that example but my application is dead in 'SpringApplication.run(SpringBootComponentScanApp.class, args);'

Comment: This time my  application run, but dont see my repository and service in applicationContext. Exist a sollution for this ?

Comment: Can you show the CrudRepository class too?

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comments use `@Entity` on your `AccountEntity`.

Insted of

```
@RestController("/account")
public class LoginController {
```

try

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("account")
public class LoginController {
```

Answer (score -1):

Show us the AccountEntity class. Is it with annotation @Entity and do you have an id from type Long. It should be something like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
    public class AccountEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Comment: Does it even relate to the issue?

Comment: Yes it relates, it will throw this kind of error if you don't have an entity as it is requested. You can check it on your own. @PaulRichard

Comment: If you see the exception at the end it says:
Error creating bean with name 'IAccountRepository' and in that place you are saying what will be the entity. If the entity is not ok this kind of exception will occur.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add @EnableJpaRepositories("your.package.name") and make sure that you have @ComponentScan("base.package.name") to SpringInitializer.

Comment: If that is the case it won't throw UnsatisfiedDependencyException.